# Ipad1 too old to be used as a test device?

Tags: ios, ipad

Do you still test iPad apps on iPad1? Is it too old to be a test device?

Does anyone know Apple's plan for this device - does it still get updates and similar stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the least powerful iPad its a good test device for iPad application performace testing. Its main limiting characteristic you're likely to run into in app development is the limited amount of RAM on the system.

It only supports up to iOS 5 though, so get one if you intend to support iOS 5 and not if you're only supporting iOS 6. If  you only want to support iOS 6 the iPad 2 is your minimum benchmark, although some functions perform more slowly on the iPad 3 (`renderInContext` is one of them) so ideally you would have both. The iPad mini, from a device perspective, is practically identical to the iPad 2 but the interface will be slightly smaller.

In summary, for a new app which only supports iOS 6 I would have an iPad mini and iPad 3 as a minimum test kit, For iOS 5 support i would recommend adding a first gen iPad to that.